# FGLRX Intel/ATI Hybrid Video, Dual-Display Flickering

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, hybrid-graphics

I'm sorry if the same question is already asked, I checked several ones but the reported problems are different or solution doesn't work.

So I've successfully installed FGLRX driver on my laptop DELL 5520 with Intel and ATI 7670 graphic cards. Had to install latest beta because stable one didn't work showing black screen. So now it seems to be working fine in Unity and Quake Live (don't have any other games or benchmarks installed). I only noticed some minor problems with graphics that can be probably solved by some tweaks (I believe so). But the problem appears when I plug second display. It is detected properly, resolution is correct I can move windows and so on but it flickers like crazy every time the picture updates. One of the solutions I've found is to run `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output VGA1 --auto --scale 1.0001x1.0001`. After that it really stops flickering but display proportions become incorrect (I see a part of the window on second display which is actually whole placed on the first). Also `amdcccle` doesn't have display config section.

My xorg.conf is generated by aticonfig:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

xorg.conf is obsolete now in Ubuntu 14.10 and I'm running a catalyst drivers without it.

I also had flickering with dual screens and I'm hoping I can fix it with something like:

```
xrandr --output DFP10 --primary
xrandr --output DFP9 --same-as DFP10
```

Still experimenting to see if that would fix the problem.